# python CSV writer - formatting

Tags: python, csv

Quick question on how to properly write data back into a CSV file using the python csv module. Currently i'm importing a file, pulling a column of dates and making a column of days_of_the_week using the datetime module. I want to then write out a new csv file (or overright the individual one) containing one original element and the new element.

```
with open('new_dates.csv') as csvfile2:
    readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    incoming = []
    for row in readCSV2:
         readin = row[0]
         time = row[1]
         year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))
         ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
         wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
         incoming.append(wkday)
         incoming.append(time)
with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(incoming))
```

Input files looks like this:

```
2017-03-02,09:25
2017-03-01,06:45
2017-02-28,23:49
2017-02-28,19:34
```

When using this code I end up with an output file that looks like this:

```
Friday
15:23
Friday
14:41
Friday
13:54
Friday
7:13
```

What I need is an output file that looks like this:

```
Friday,15:23
Friday,14:41
Friday,13:54
Friday,7:13
```

If I change the delimiter in out_file.write to a comma I just get one element of data per column, like this:

```
Friday  15:23   Friday 14:41  Friday 13:54  ....
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem might be this join operation: `'\n'.join(incoming)`. Try replacing that _\n_ with a space to get the desired output; for a real csv, use _","_

Comment: using a space results all data in one long row, instead of two CSV columns. And as noted the use of a comma results in each value in a different field in a single row.

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: print wkday
print time

Thursday
16:45
Wednesday
20:42
Monday
12:12
Saturday
07:08

Comment: Please edit the question to show the input file that creates the output.  Make it reproducible.

Comment: added a snippet of the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want `Friday` in column 0 and the time in column 1, so you need to change your `incoming` to a list of lists. That means the append statement should look like this:

```
...
    incoming.append([wkday, time])
...
```

Then, it is better to use the `csv.writer` to write back to the file. You can write the whole `incoming` in one go without worrying about formatting.

```
with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(incoming)
```

Comment: Results in an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./analyze.py", line 35, in <module>
    out_file.write('\n'.join(incoming))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: @Justin Check the answer as it currently stands - I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Being somewhat unclear on what format you want, I've assumed you just want a single space between `wkday` and `time`.  For a quick fix, instead of appending both `wkday` and `time` separately, as in your example, append them together:

```
...
    incoming.append('{} {}'.format(wkday,time))
...
```

**OR**, build your `incoming` as a list of lists:

```
...
    incoming.append([wkday,time])
...
```

and change your write to:

```
with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join([' '.join(t) for t in incoming]))
```

Comment: Using that method seems to yield the same results as replace the \n with a space. All the data goes into a single field.

Comment: The second option makes some even stranger results. All data is in a single column and each field is one character.

Comment: @Justin sorry, missed a chunk out - above should work now

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./analyze.py", line 32, in <module>
    out_file.write('\n'.join(' '.join(incoming)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the `csv` module for this.  I'm guessing at the input, but from the description it looks like:

```
2017-03-02,09:25
2017-03-01,06:45
2017-02-28,23:49
2017-02-28,19:34
```

This will parse it and write it in a new format:

```
import datetime
with open('new_dates.csv') as f1, open('new_dates2.csv','w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(line.strip(),'%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M')
        f2.write(dt.strftime('%A,%H:%M\n'))
```

Output file:

```
Thursday,09:25
Wednesday,06:45
Tuesday,23:49
Tuesday,19:34
```

Comment: This is assuming there's nothing else in the input file. OP seems to want CSV output too.

Comment: @Stuart The question changed since I wrote this, but still, adding a comma is a slight modification to the `strftime`.  No assuming involved, since the OP also added the input.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your incoming array is a linear list. So, you should have been doing is something like following:

```
#your incoming array
incoming = ['Friday', '15:23', 'Friday', '14:41', 'Friday', '13:54', 'Friday', '7:13']

#actual parsing of the array for correct output
for i,j in zip(incoming[::2], incoming[1::2]):
        out_file.write(','.join((i,j)))
        out_file.write('\n')
```